# .htaccess | Too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to add a IP filter into my `.htaccess` file, but after I applied it, a *too many redirects* error will show.

Content of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule ^ /test.php [R=302,L]
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Because if your `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` matches, you'll send a `Location` header of `/test.php` which your browser will redirect to. At that point it will match the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` and `^` and then send a `Location` header of `/test.php`. At that point....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to do two things here:

1. Force HTTPS and *www.*
2. Redirect to `test.php` if a certain IP is making the request

The issue you were facing was due to the fact that even though the IP address was being matched, it was still being checked for when reaching `test.php`. As there would be a match again, the redirect would loop continuously. By adding the appropriate condition, we check to see that the requested URI is not `test.php` before checking the IP addresses. The line in question is shown near the bottom of my answer, which includes enhancements to your original code.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to test.php if a certain IP is matched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test\.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule ^ /test.php [R=302,L]
```

If you need to match multiple IP addresses, then you should make use of the `OR` flag for every IP address except the last one:

```bsh
# Redirect to test.php if a certain set of IPs are matched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test\.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule ^ /test.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Indeed - I had thought the loop was coming from the test for `www.`. Will update my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I do something to hide the url? So, if I want to redirect to a file in a subfolder, how can I rewrite the displayed url?, like "/test/index.html" -> "/".

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you have a new question, please [ask it separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), as your original question has been answered. As a side-note, however, I think that's impractical. Better to redirect to a separate page. However, you could create a rule that maps `/test` to `/test.php` before checking for the IP addresses. Then you could redirect to `/test`.

Comment: Finally!  An answer that actually works!  Thank you, sir!